# Trying to simplify my code using loops but I'm not sure how to insert the iterator in the loop

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone could help me out here. I've tried just about everything that comes to mind so now I am more interested if my approach is even possible.

`charSelect` is a function I am using to set up objects using a class  constructor. `w1` and `t1` are global objects set up using this function and `Status` is a function to print out the object's attributes.

I am using `try` and `except` statements because either `w1` or `t1` won't exist based on the users input, so I'm using the `try` and `except` statements to avoid attribute errors. Probably a pretty bad workaround but I couldn't think of a better way to handle it.

Basically I am trying to simplify a long series of statements like this:

```
try:
    charSelect.w1.Status()
except:
    charSelect.t1.Status()

try:
    charSelect.w2.Status()
except:
    charSelect.t2.Status()

try:
    charSelect.w3.Status()
except:
    charSelect.t3.Status()
```

Into a loop like this:

```
i = 1
while (i <= 3):
    try:
        charSelect.w[i] .Status()
    except:
        charSelect.t[i].Status()
i += 1
```

Comment: I need some context, what is `charSelect` ?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Hard to understand whats going on here with this.

Comment: I've edited my original post, hope this provides a bit more clarity. If not then let me know.

Comment: your edit does not clarify much, but i could suggest you: in your charSelect class create a property almacening all the w and t as lists.. `charSelect.objList = [w1,w2,t3,...] then you could use a for to get all the status

Comment: instead of separated variables you should use lists `w` and `t` - and then you can use `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try implementing lists.

Comment: Thanks to those suggesting I use a list. After figuring out how to implement them I found they work quite well and simplify my code by quite a bit. Cheers.